# Powershell script that calls Python script works correctly in ISE but not in Task Scheduler

Tags: python, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I am having an issue that has been asked before but my issue seems to be a bit different as my Powershell script calls a Python script and when doing so from Task Scheduler it runs as if it is working but It doesnt seem to place the CSV files in the correct directory. In fact I have no idea where it is placing / is even creating the CSV files. I am not sure if Powershell script calling Python script may be the problem. Perhaps Task Scheduler does not support this.

The Python script scrapes data off of the web site and places the files in the directory that the Python script (uplink.py) is in.

Please see below script:

```
# CSV Path Variables
$csvappliancepath = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Meraki Store CSVs\Appliances"
$csvotherpath = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Meraki Store CSVs\Other"
$csvinroot = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\*.csv"
$csvnewpath = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Meraki Store CSVs"

# CSV Variables for renaming
$csvappoldname = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Check appliances -$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).csv"
$csvotholdname = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Check other devices -$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')).csv"
$csvothnewname = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Check other devices -$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss')).csv"
$csvappnewname = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Check appliances -$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss')).csv"

# CSV Item Variables for Import
$csvappnewitem = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Meraki Store CSVs\Appliances\Cash Converters Southern Africa appliances -$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss')).csv"

# CSV Exclusion file
$csvexclitem = "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Excluded Stores CSV\Meraki CSV Email Exclusions.csv"

# LOG Variables
$CurrentPath = Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Parent  
$LogPath = Join-Path -Path $CurrentPath -ChildPath 'Logs'
$LogRootName = (Split-Path -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Leaf) -replace '\.ps1'
$TimeStamp = Get-Date -Format yyyyMMdd_HHmmss
$LogFileName = '{0}_{1}.log' -f $LogRootName, $TimeStamp
$LogFile = Join-Path -Path $LogPath -ChildPath $LogFileName
$NumberOfLogsToKeep = 10
 
If(Test-Path -Path $LogPath)
    
    {
    # Perform some cleanup and keep only the most recent ones
        $Filter = '{0}_????????_??????.log' -f (Join-Path -Path $LogPath -ChildPath $LogRootName)
 
        Get-ChildItem -Path $Filter |
        Sort-Object -Property LastWriteTime -Descending |
        Select-Object -Skip $NumberOfLogsToKeep |
        Remove-Item -Verbose
    }
    Else
    {
    # No logs to clean but create the Logs folder
    New-Item -Path $LogPath -ItemType Directory -Verbose
    }
 
Start-Transcript -Path $Logfile

# Run Python Script and wait for process to end before proceeding
if (!(Get-Process "pythonw" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue))

    {   
        Start-Process "C:\Python\pythonw.exe" -ArgumentList '-u "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\uplink.py"' -Wait
    }
    else
    {
        Get-Process "pythonw" | Stop-Process -Force
        Start-Process "C:\Python\pythonw.exe" -ArgumentList '-u "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\uplink.py"' -Wait
    }


# Tests to see if the CSV items exist then renames, imports and moves the files
if ((Get-Item -Path $csvappoldname -ErrorAction Continue) -and 
    (Get-Item -Path $csvotholdname -ErrorAction Continue))

    {       
        Rename-Item -Path $csvappoldname -NewName $csvappnewname -ErrorAction Continue
        Rename-Item -Path $csvotholdname -NewName $csvothnewname -ErrorAction Continue

        $merakicsv = Import-Csv $csvappnewname -ErrorAction Continue
        $merakicsvexcl = Import-Csv $csvexclitem -ErrorAction Continue

        Get-Item -Path "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\*Appliances*" | 
            Move-Item -Destination $csvappliancepath -ErrorAction Continue

        Get-Item -Path "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\*other*" | 
            Move-Item -Destination $csvotherpath -ErrorAction Continue
    }
     else
    {
        Write-Host "API scrape CSV and/or Exclusion CSV is possibly missing so renaming, CSV import and moving of item could not execute. Investigation is required."
        Break
    }

# Foreach to iterate through CSV selected rows and send email alerts based on results
foreach ($row in $merakicsv) {
   
    if($($row.Network) -notin $merakicsvexcl.Network)
       
        {
        if ($row.'WAN1 Status' -eq 'Ready')
            {
                Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $sender -Subject "$($row.Network) WAN1 is Ready!" -Body "$($row.Network) $wan1ready" -SmtpServer $smtpserver
            }
        if ($row.'WAN1 Status' -eq 'Failed')
            {
                Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $sender -Subject "$($row.Network) WAN1 is Failed!" -Body "$($row.Network) $wan1failed" -SmtpServer $smtpserver
            }
        if ($row.'WAN2 Status' -eq 'Failed')
            {
                Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $sender -Subject "$($row.Network) WAN2 is Failed!" -Body "$($row.Network) $wan2failed" -SmtpServer $smtpserver
            }    
        if ($row.'WAN1 Status' -eq 'Not connected')
            {
                Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $sender -Subject "$($row.Network) WAN1 is Not connected!" -Body "$($row.Network) $wan1notconnected" -SmtpServer $smtpserver
            }  
        if ($row.'WAN2 Status' -eq 'Not connected')
            {
                Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $sender -Subject "$($row.Network) WAN2 is Not connected!" -Body "$($row.Network) $wan2notconnected" -SmtpServer $smtpserver
            }      
    }
       
}

Stop-Transcript
```

When I run this from ISE as admin or console as SYSTEM the script works 100%. When it starts the pythonw process with the Python script arguments it creates the CSV files in the correct folder for my script to proceed correctly. However when I run it from Task Scheduler it appears to run pythonw process and after it is done it fails as it cannot find the CSV files.

Task Scheduler Details
Running as SYSTEM
Program: powershell.exe
Arguments: -NoProfile -NoLogo -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File "C:\Stuff\Scripts\Meraki Health Checks\Automated_Health_Checks.ps1"

Not sure where it would be placing these CSV files.

I have been racking my brain trying to figure this out but I am at a total loss now. If someone could please advise me on how to tackle this issue I will greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What are the conditions under which task scheduler runs the script in question?  As in, what is the event trigger(s)?  Also, I can see how you would schedule the task to run as system, but when testing the script, how were you testing the script manually from a powershell console running as system?  Was this console window running as system elevated as well?  Could it just be you need to run the command with the highest privileges?

Comment: The script is meant to run daily at 8 AM. The conditions are check boxes are all deselected. I have been triggering it manually to test if it is working correctly. I am running with Highest Privileges.

I was able to test on a console running as System by using PSEXEC from Sysinternals and running Powershell.exe. This then opens it as the system.

I can do the job successfully with 2 separate scripts and 2 scheduled tasks but I would like to have 1 script to do the work and not 2.